# Form action with PHP

Tags: php, forms

I have a form, and I am trying to use the `input` to append to the form action. Here is my form code:

```
<form ACTION="_update/update.php?orderId=<?php $_POST['orderId']; ?>" name="msChangeForm" method="POST">
  <fieldset>
    <p>
      <label for="orderId">What is you order number?</label><br />
      <input name="orderId" type="text" id="orderId" value="" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Next"/>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I keep getting this error:

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: orderId in C:\wamp\www\ms\test.php on
>   line 48 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0020140184{main}(
>   )..\test.php:0 " name="msChangeForm" method="POST">

Even though I get the error, the form works. I know I need some PHP code for this form, but I have no idea what to use.

Comment: Unless you have some JavaScript code to modify the DOM after the user inputs their order ID, the URL in the action attribute won't change since the PHP is processed before the page is sent to the user. You should be able to use the browser's developer tools, or even view the source, to see what the action parameter's URL is.

Comment: It means `$_POST['orderId']` is empty. So it is submitting to `_update/update.php?orderId=` with no order id.

Comment: Are you sure that you're posting to this page that your form is on? In order for this code to work, some other form would have to post to this `test.php` page. Usually forms post to processing pages, not pages with other forms on them. Perhaps you meant `$_GET['orderId']` instead?

Comment: I tried $_GET['orderId] with same result

Comment: Are you trying to use variables from the `$_POST` array before the form is posted? Remember that the PHP is parsed and HTML is rendered (thus attempting to complete your ACTION URL) before the user submits the form. Shouldn't you instead be using a hidden input form element for `orderId`? What advantage is it to you to have the `orderId` posted in the ACTION URL instead of as a form variable? That is unusual.

Comment: I am trying to post to a form an another page

Comment: You'll want to sanitise the POST variable before using it for security. For example, I could make a POST request from another site, setting the parameter for orderId to something like `10"><script>alert('do something nasty');</script>`.

Comment: "I am trying to post to a form an another page"
Unless this form comes up AS THE RESULT OF another POST, the `$_POST` array will always be empty (contain no keys) when this page loads. If this script is, in fact, being rendered as the result of a POST from another page, use `print_r( $_POST )` to see what you are receiving from that other form.

Comment: Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way. What I'm trying to accomplish is have the user enter a number into the form. Then use that number, which is a primary key in a MySQL database table, retrieve that record on a new page. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

When you first load the page, it's requested using the HTTP [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) method, so `$_POST` is empty.

The simplest workaround is to replace `$_POST['orderId']` to `isset($_POST['orderId']) ? $_POST['orderId'] : ''`.

Comment: Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way. What I'm trying to accomplish is have the user enter a number into the form. Then use that number, which is a primary key in a MySQL database table, retrieve that record on a new page. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Michael basically it's okay. The only problem is the first page load: the form is not yet submitted, so there is just no `orderId` and that's why you get notice. And if you always submit to another page, I think you even need no `orderId` in query string (just leave `action="_update/update.php"` in form.

Comment: The crazy thing is the form works like is supposed to but it has a warning and the warning is on the form page not the destination page

Comment: So you just need to remove `$_POST['orderId']` from the form page as it's unnecessary there.

Comment: Or use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST`?

Comment: @PeterMortensen `$_REQUEST` also catches `$_GET`, which can be undesired.

Answer (score 0):

It means `$_POST['orderId']` is empty. So it is submitting to `_update/update.php?orderId=` with no order id. However it works because you then submit the form and have the user input `orderId` so you should only the notice the first time you load the page. You don't need it in the action anyway, that would actually be `$_GET['orderId']` not post.